# how to keep selected option after refresh the page

Tags: html, django, django-3.0

I trying to implement filter option with django I can do the filtering, but can't keep the selected option after the refresh because I am rendering the filtered result, any solution?

views.py

```
def filter(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    print(products)
    if request.method == 'POST':
      title = request.POST.get('da',None)
      print(title)
      titre = Product.objects.filter(title=title)
      print(titre)
      return render(request, 'searchapp/searchview.html', {'qs': titre,'ds':products})



    return render(request,'searchapp/searchview.html',{'qs':products})
```

html :

```
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'search:query' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                  <select name="da" class="form-control">
                        {% for obj in qs %}
                 <option value="{{obj}}">{{obj}}</option>
                         {%endfor%}

                         </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add Product</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Admin Filters Use a GET request. That solves your problem:

```
title = request.GET.get('da',None)
```

```
<form action="{% url 'search:query' %}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: maybe you still have `if request.method == 'POST':` ? The new version would be more like: `title = request.GET.get('da',None)` and then `if title:`

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to use GET :

views.py

```
def filter(request):
      products = Product.objects.all()
      print(products)
      title = request.GET.get('da',None)
      print(title)
      titre = Product.objects.filter(title=title)
      print(titre)
      return render(request, 'searchapp/searchview.html', {'qs': titre,'ds':products})



      return render(request,'searchapp/searchview.html',{'qs':products})
```

html.py

```
   <form action="{% url 'search:query' %}" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                  <select name="da" id="da" class="form-control">
                        {% for obj in ds %}
                 <option value="{{obj}}">{{obj}}</option>
                         {%endfor%}
<!--                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">-->
                         </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add Product</button>
        </form>
</div>
```